# How do I access the count of this object

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

Any Idea how to access the count of this object ? I tried this but it returns null.

```
int countNumber = inWebFormData.Count
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the tag of the language you're using

Comment: Post code, not pictures

Comment: this will work. its dynamic. so if its passed correctly itll work

Comment: also `int` cant be null at all ! are you sure you are correctly pointing the problem?

Comment: @GrantWinney I get an exception throw that says "Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type".

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary exactly so it throws me to a exception that states that its null.

Comment: in your image from debug i dont see null.

Comment: there is a value in Count but when i try "int countNumber = inWebFormData.Count " It throws an error that states "Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type" @M.kazemAkhgary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the property of base class. so you have to cast it to base class and get the count.

```
dynamic baseInWebFormData = Convert.ChangeType(inWebFormData, inWebFormData.GetType().BaseType);
int countNumber = baseInWebFormData.Count; // will be 2
```

If it still says "Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type"  then use `int?`

also to access any property that refers to base class you have to use `baseInWebFormData`.

I give this solution because you didnt know the base class name. but if you do you can directly cast it to base class.

```
BaseClass baseInWebFormData = (BaseClass)inWebFormData;
int countNumber = baseInWebFormData.Count;
```

Comment: Good suggestion but as you can see there is clearly a Count that is 2 in inWebFormData and I'm trying to access it. But the problem is that it returns null it doesn't match the Count value of 2

Comment: what is the name of the class and base class @ExPlOiD

Comment: I'm sorry but I cant seem to find the name of the base class. But I've complied a few image that shows everything that you need to know. It would be nice if you could help me spot the base class name . http://imgur.com/a/OvrH3